# How to find href links that start with a certain keyword using beautiful soup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, href

The task I am doing right now is very monotonous. In this task I have to go to this website [eg page](https://nclt.gov.in/order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ==&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg==&page=19). You can see that there is a hyperlink attached to each case in the **Status** column. I am trying to find a way in which I can grab certain `href` that start with keyword `case-details`. As they are the links from **status** column for each particular case. Since the hyperlinks contain details regarding the cases.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
```

```
url = "https://nclt.gov.in/order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ==&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg==&page=40"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Which gives the following **output** (added line numbers for clarity..):

```
....
44 /order-judge-wise
45 order-judgement-date-wise
46 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ3MjAxOQ==
47 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ4MjAyMA==
48 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ4MjAyMQ==
49 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUwMjAyMQ==
50 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUxMjAyMA==
51 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUyMjAyMA==
52 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUzMjAyMA==
53 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUzMjAyMQ==
54 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjU1MjAyMQ==
55 case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjU3MjAyMQ==
56 order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ==&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg==&page=39 
57 order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ==&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg==&page=1 
....
```

I want to grab the `href` links that start with "`case-details`" and put them into a list. Which I later use to scrap details of each case and put them into an excel file.

Till now I've tried to make a loop that looks for these links:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if "case" in link.get_text():
        print(link['href'])
```

But till now, no success, I also want to know how to make this into a list.

expected output:

```
url_list1 = ["case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTAzMjAyMA==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA1MjAyMQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA2MjAyMQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA3MjAyMQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA4MjAxNw==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA4MjAyMQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA5MjAyMA==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTA5MjAyMQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTEwMjAxOQ==",
"case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMTEwMjAyMQ=="]
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting only these `<a>` with `href` starts with `case-details` you could use `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('a[href^="case-details"]')
```

be aware you have to prepend a baseUrl e.g. with `list comprehension`:

```
['https://nclt.gov.in/'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href^="case-details"]')]
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://nclt.gov.in/order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ==&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg==&page=40"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

urls = ['https://nclt.gov.in/'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href^="case-details"]')]
```

##### Output

```
['https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ3MjAxOQ==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ4MjAyMA==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjQ4MjAyMQ==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUwMjAyMQ==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUxMjAyMA==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUyMjAyMA==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUzMjAyMA==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjUzMjAyMQ==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjU1MjAyMQ==',
 'https://nclt.gov.in/case-details?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ==&filing_no=MzMwNTExODAwMjU3MjAyMQ==']
```